# My brightness key is lagging severely and sometimes doesn't work at all on 14.04 LTS (HP Stream 11)

Tags: keyboard, brightness

This is what happens when I try to lower the brightness - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5HEVHx7roQ.

When I start up my laptop, it dims the brightness and I can't see some of the screen with the matte screen.

Comment: Can anyone help me?